# C++: multiple MPI_Recv in same scope

Tags: c++, mpi

I have implemented a program utilizing MPI for message passing on a cluster. However, I have some trouble understanding how the MPI_Recv function works.

The below snippet is supposed to yield the output

```
First string: firstString
Second string: secondString
```

However, the output occasionally becomes

```
First string: firstString
Second string: secondStringfirstString
```

The code:

```
if (rank == 1){
                std::string firstString;
                std::string secondString;
                MPI_Status status1;
                MPI_Probe(0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status1);
                int count1;
                MPI_Get_count(&status1,MPI_CHAR,&count1);
                char firstBuf [count1];
                MPI_Recv(&firstBuf,count1,MPI_CHAR,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status1);
                firstString = firstBuf;

                MPI_Status status2;
                int count2;
                MPI_Probe(0,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status2);
                MPI_Get_count(&status2,MPI_CHAR,&count2);
                char secBuf [count2];
                MPI_Recv(&secBuf,count2,MPI_CHAR,0,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status2);
                secondString = secBuf;

                std::cout << "First string: " << firstString << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Second string: " << secondString << std::endl;

            } else {

                std::string firstString = "firstString";
                std::string secondString = "secondString";
MPI_Send(&firstString[0],firstString.size(),MPI_CHAR,1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Send(&secondString[0],secondString.size(),MPI_CHAR,1,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
```

I figured I was able to avoid this behaviour by wrapping one or both of the receive blocks, so that the first goes out of scope before the second is performed. The following snippet shows the working code:

```
        if (rank == 1){
                std::string firstString;
                std::string secondString;
                if (true){
                    MPI_Status status1;
                    MPI_Probe(0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status1);
                    int count1;
                    MPI_Get_count(&status1,MPI_CHAR,&count1);
                    char firstBuf [count1];
                    MPI_Recv(&firstBuf,count1,MPI_CHAR,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status1);
                    firstString = firstBuf;
                }
                if (true){
                    MPI_Status status2;
                    int count2;
                    MPI_Probe(0,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status2);
                    MPI_Get_count(&status2,MPI_CHAR,&count2);
                    char secBuf [count2];
                    MPI_Recv(&secBuf,count2,MPI_CHAR,0,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status2);
                    firstString = firstBuf;
                }
                std::cout << "First string: " << firstString << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Second string: " << secondString << std::endl;

            } else {

                std::string firstString = "firstString";
                std::string secondString = "secondString";
MPI_Send(&firstString[0],firstString.size(),MPI_CHAR,1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Send(&secondString[0],secondString.size(),MPI_CHAR,1,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
```

What is the rationale for this? Is this the usual approach for sending multiple strings, or should one serialize the two strings and send in one message?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] of the first code. The version you show makes no sense, you don't even assign or declare `secondString` anywhere.

Comment: You need to manually `NULL` terminate the received strings.

Comment: Yeah, that was bad @Zulan. The code is updated, and hopefully it makes more sense now!

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Nice, thank you! Why is secBuf affected by the contents of firstBuf?

Comment: It's just undefined for both cases, anything may happen - the correct result, a wrong one or a crash.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Turns out it could be solved simply by using firstParent.size()+1 and secondParent.size()+1 in the send operations, as suggested by @Zulan in [Behaviour of MPI_Send and MPI_Recv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167437/behavior-of-mpi-send-and-mpi-recv).